# Understanding an Equation for Pulmonary Diffusion

Tags: calculus, chemistry

I've been reviewing some medical documentation in preparation for school and I'm having some trouble understanding how to think of an equation in the paper [The physiological basis of pulmonary gas exchange: implications for clinical interpretation of arterial blood gases](http://erj.ersjournals.com/content/45/1/227.long). The equation is available below:

$$V'_{0_2} = V'_{E} * ( F_{IO_2} - F_{EO_2} ) $$

While the paragraphs before and after the equation describe each part of the equation, this particular algebra student (me) is being thrown through a loop (I haven't take chemistry yet either). The article seems to group this into a simple three term equation $x = (a (b-c))$. But as I look at it I see symbols such as $V'$ and the use of $O_2$ as a part of a term meant to be viewed as Oxygen and not as $O * 2$. So my question is am I right in how I'm viewing this? Is it really as simple as a three term equation? Also, is this common? And does the ' in $V'$ a common way of expressing something other than the volume that it's expressing in the paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything besides $V'$ and $F$ is a subscript. The prime can mean many things, but here it means time derivative. Notice the units for $V_E'$: it’s a rate of change in volume.

Comment: Thanks, I now know what to research (primes) in regards to the ' symbol. Then the IO2 and EO2 as prime values are meant to simply say that $F$ in each instance is intended to be the inspired O2 and expired O2? So to simplify it you could say $x = a * (b - c)$ where $a$ is the volume of ventilated gases in $L*min^-1$, b is the volume of inspired O2, and c is the volume of expired O2? Also, what college MAT class would go into primes?

Comment: @Kirkland You’ll have to read the paper for the meaning of all of the symbols used, which I’m not going to do, but yes, the equation is of the form $x=a(b-c)$. I doubt that $F$ stands for a volume because the units don’t match.

Comment: @Kirkland  Don’t confuse the name of the symbol “$'$” with *prime numbers*. The prime accent is just a textual modifier that is used in many ways in mathematics. Sometimes it’s just a way to generate a new variable name, sometimes it means the transpose of a matrix, sometimes it means time derivative, &c. You have to figure out the meaning from context.

Comment: Oh no, I understood that part after your answer. I would still like to know what college math class might go into using the prime symbol. Or maybe this is something I'd see more in a chemistry class?

Comment: @Kirkland There’s no class per se. Primes appear everywhere, even in high-school courses such as geometry. Its use to indicate a time rate of change comes from calculus.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think I can go forward from here.